# Sorting PostgreSQL Grouped Results in Table A by Last Update Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL tables, 'A' and 'B', with the following structures:

Table 'A':

- id: primary key with auto-increment
- res_id: foreign key referencing table 'B'
- description: table description
- last_update: date type

Table 'B':

- id: integer primary key with auto-increment
- description: varchar(256)

I need assistance with constructing a query that involves grouping by `res_id` in table 'A' and sorting the results based on the `last_update` date from table 'A'. How can I achieve this?

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT count(id),res_id 
from A GROUP BY res_id
ORDER BY id last_update;
```

Answer (score 2):

To group records by **res_id** and sort them based on the maximum (**max**) value of the **latest_update** field within each group, you can include the max(latest_update) function in your select query. This allows you to first group the records by **res_id** and then select the maximum (**max**) date for each group. Finally, you can sort the entire result set based on this maximum date.

Here's an example of how you can construct the query:

```
SELECT res_id, max(latest_update) AS max_date
FROM table_A
GROUP BY res_id
ORDER BY max_date;
```

Comment: Both of your current answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.